# What is mounted on what with xfs; storage drivers for docker

Tags: mount, docker, xfs, device-mapper

I have a virtual redhat linux machine, that I am using for Docker. Apparently, I haven't set it properly up for production mode as I am still running the storage mode as a loop-back device with devicemapper ([1](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/)). In the end, I want to configure docker to use the `overlay2` filesystem as per [2](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/).

My issue is that I don't know how to interpret the output from `df` as to how my file system has been put together. It's quite different from the old-fashioned 1-2 harddrives mounted as `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`.

`df`:

```
Filesystem            1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root  18348032 16437056   1910976  90% /
devtmpfs                1913900        0   1913900   0% /dev
tmpfs                   1930752        0   1930752   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   1930752   201648   1729104  11% /run
tmpfs                   1930752        0   1930752   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                508588   273748    234840  54% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel-data  31442944   119460  31323484   1% /data
tmpfs                    386152       12    386140   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    386152        0    386152   0% /run/user/982
/dev/dm-4              10475520   196220  10279300   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cc19510c0309762e0dbc9f3dfe21900d969f926c6ef04ed7d11b7bdeede89f91
/dev/dm-5              10475520    59804  10415716   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/5a7a640f1488988864923b943a5c69204fc6f731aedc27400898d3c9c35577ab
shm                       65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/1b3a8d5dac84e7cc9be3956049bb9902f4c56c1af644e7b2bf9572d69b49585f/mounts/shm
shm                       65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/765355272efb9e0ab8aa1fd1a12de59753f44e494713e7e2345820cb2a9d5c31/mounts/shm
tmpfs                    386152        0    386152   0% /run/user/959053690
/dev/dm-6              10475520  1947752   8527768  19% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/533250fcc6d43b1918fff0062a177848fda9ef9343e3fd0ab01de86bb58bfdc8
shm                       65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/f84698c4831b2771009ad85ccd0cbb82b420d7ac0bcd60edfbbe9556fe360feb/mounts/shm
tmpfs                    386152        0    386152   0% /run/user/959055879
```

I've included output from `xfs_info` on two filesystems below, but am unsure whether one of these are the storages used by the docker containers and volumes mounted on the containers:

```
$ xfs_info /dev/mapper/rhel-root
meta-data=/dev/mapper/rhel-root  isize=256    agcount=5, agsize=1144832 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=4589568, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0

$ xfs_info /dev/mapper/rhel-data
meta-data=/dev/mapper/rhel-data  isize=256    agcount=7, agsize=1280000 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=7863296, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

Could somebody be so kind to walk me through this?